# Globally stop editors from creating ~ files

Tags: editors

Is there a global setting to prevent all text editors from creating backup files? I'm sick of changing it in 11 different places.

Comment: Converted [alex](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1946/alex)'s answer to a comment: "But these backups could save you life one day :)"

Comment: I save my important stuff to dropbox. It just makes a mess to have versions of backups stored to dropbox =P

Comment: You just have to wait until dropbox allows you to ignore all those files :-) https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/648/ignore-file

Comment: Or you could just write a script that just automatically removes all files matching `*~`

Comment: Instead of turning them off, consider putting them in a designated temp folder. That solves your dropbox problems while keeping the backup files around if you ever need them. I know emacs will let you do this, can't speak for any other editors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually makes a rather strong argument for "learn one editor well".

FWIW, the .vimrc statement would be "set nobackup".

Comment: Thanks for the vim setting. That's the one that really matters I guess since most other editors can be changed in menus.

Comment: Downvotes? Seriously?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no single environment variable or configuration setting that is checked by every UNIX editor.

For Emacs, you can turn off file backups for all files by inserting this into your `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq backup-enable-predicate (lambda (path) nil))
```

GEdit has a boolean configuration key `/apps/gedit-2/preferences/editor/save/create_backup_copy` that you can set with `gconf-tool`.

I'm quite sure there are as many ways to turn backups off as there are editors. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there is no cross-editor configuration options.  But, here is one pathological solution:

1. Write a script that does something like the following:

   ```
   find / -iname "*~" -exec rm {} \;
   ```
2. Add this script as a cron job that runs every so many minutes.

If you are just interested in keeping your dropbox folder clean, change the `/` to the appropriate folder.  I'll bet an even more interesting solution can be created by using [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en).

Answer (score 1):

There is an environment variable `VERSION_CONTROL` which works for Emacs and other Gnu utilities (unless some gnome inside my computer has been fooling me or something). Whether this works for other things I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use a read-only filesystem.

Comment: That's not even close to an answer

Comment: One of the only reasonable motives to avoid creating '~' files is to avoid writing to the filesystem, right?